# enforcing some task in case of gruntjs build failure

Tags: javascript, gruntjs

I want to force grunt to execute some tasks, in case some of the tasks failed during grunt build, something like finaly block. is it feasible?

Comment: I mean can I configure some tasks like that? whether there is any grunt library that can accomplish that.

Answer (score 1):

Append your the grunt command you're invoking with the `--force` flag